# Want to include email in the error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
export const validAccount = {
  email: 'onetwo@gmail.com',
  password: 'one123345',
};
```

I want to include the `validAccount.email` in the following error message:

```
const errorMessageSignUp = {
  emailRegisteredInSystem: 'User with email '(validAccount.email),' is already exists.',
};
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to, as I am getting the following error:

> Error Message:  (property) ' is already exists.': any ':'
>   expected.ts(1005)

Comment: Besides the JavaScript syntax issue, your error message has invalid English syntax (drop the "is").

Comment: Replace with this: ` `User with email ${validAccount.email} already exists.` `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```js
const errorMessageSignUp = {
  emailRegisteredInSystem: 'User with email '(validAccount.email),' is already exists.',
};
```

with

```js
const errorMessageSignUp = {
  emailRegisteredInSystem: `User with email ${validAccount.email} already exists.`,
};
```

**or** with

```js
const errorMessageSignUp = {
  emailRegisteredInSystem: 'User with email '+String(validAccount.email)+'  already exists.',
};
```

Comment: Thanks mate. this one is working. 

`const errorMessageSignUp = {
  emailRegisteredInSystem: 'User with email '+String(validAccount.email)+'  already exists.',
};`

Comment: Method 1 should also work. Note that in method 1, we have backticks (``) around the string and not quotation marks (""). Make sure you didn't do this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try to use template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

So your string should be: `User with email ${validAccount.email} already exists.```
don't forget the back-ticks ``.

Also, this works: `'User with email ' + validAccount.email + ' already exists.'`